# flutter using nested list of object in pagaview builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a nested list of object in a PageView builder,
bellow is shown how my data is structured

```
  [
    {
      "id": "001",
      "qtn":
          "In how many ways can a committee of 4 people be chosen out of 8 people?",
      "option": {"a": "32", "b": "52", "c": "70", "d": "79"}
    },
    {
      "id": "002",
      "qtn":
          "In how many ways, a committee of 6 members be selected from 7 men and 5 ladies, consisting of 4 men and 2 ladies?",
      "option": {"a": "250", "b": "350", "c": "450", "d": "550"}
    },
    {
      "id": "003",
      "qtn":
          "A committee of 5 members is to be formed by selecting out 4 men and 5 women. In how many different ways the committee can be formed if it should have 2 men and 3 women?",
      "option": {"a": "30", "b": "60", "c": "70", "d": "80"}
    },
    {
      "id": "004",
      "qtn":
          "In how many ways can a committee of 4 people be chosen out of 8 people?",
      "option": {"a": "32", "b": "52", "c": "70", "d": "79"}
    },
    {
      "id": "005",
      "qtn":
          "In how many ways can a committee of 4 people be chosen out of 8 people?",
      "option": {"a": "32", "b": "52", "c": "70", "d": "79"}
    },
    {
      "id": "006",
      "qtn":
          "In how many ways can a committee of 4 people be chosen out of 8 people?",
      "option": {"a": "32", "b": "52", "c": "70", "d": "79"}
    },
  ];
```

This is what my list now looks like after I've restructured it,
I also have a model named QuestionModel, which contains id(string), qtn(string) and option as a nested class which has its option a,b,c, and d as string

```
 List<QuestionModel> questionList = [
    QuestionModel(
      id:"001",
        qtn:"In how many ways can a committee of 4 people be chosen out of 8 people?",
        option: Option
       
        ),
    QuestionModel(
      id:"002",
      qtn:
        "In how many ways, a committee of 6 members be selected from 7 men and 5 ladies, consisting of 4 men and 2 ladies?",
      option:Option),
    QuestionModel(
      id:"003",
      qtn:
        "A committee of 5 members is to be formed by selecting out 4 men and 5 women. In how many different ways the committee can be formed if it should have 2 men and 3 women?",
        option:Option),

        
  ];

  List<Option> optionList = [
    Option(a: "32", b: "52", c: "70", d: "79"),
    Option(a: "250", b: "350", c: "450", d: "550"),
    Option(a: "70", b: "60", c: "70", d: "80"),
  ];
```

And this is what i have tried, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
Flexible(
        fit: FlexFit.tight,
        child: PageView.builder(
            controller: homeViewModel.pageController,
            onPageChanged: homeViewModel.openNextIndex,
            itemCount: homeViewModel.questionList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            
              return Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Column(children: [
                      Container(
                        height: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical! * 16,
                        child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              //question
                              Text(
                                  homeViewModel.questionList[index].qtn)
                            ]),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: AppSizes.large_dimension),
                        //option
                        Text(homeViewModel.questionList[index].option.a),
                        Text(homeViewModel.questionList[index].option.b),
                        Text(homeViewModel.questionList[index].option.c),
                        Text(homeViewModel.questionList[index].option.d),



                  
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }));
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is not working, what error you are getting etc.?

Comment: thanks @Wiktor, im working on a quiz app, and i want to render both the question and the options in a pageview builder, so that when i swipe the pageview it render the next question and option from the list